# UIView memory crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, uiview

I have got `GMSMapView`and on it I want to have additional UIView with UITableView.

```
let shopListView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 500))
shopListView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 500))
shopListView.addSubview(tableView!)
tableView!.delegate = self
tableView!.dataSource = self
tableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "explore")
self.mapView.addSubview(shopListView)
print(tableView!.delegate)
tableView!.reloadData()
```

After some changes I am showing this view like

```
func showShopViewList() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.shopListView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

And hiding in the same way.

The problem is - memory consumed is 300 mb, if there is no adding this view - 60 mb, and iPhone 4s is crashing cause it is to hard for him. Can you give some advice to realize this function?

Comment: this might occur because if you are adding view multiple times & not removing it.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: do not use `!` inconsiderably. Use `if let` and `guard`. Do not create views by hand: use a *storyboard*. This will allow you to clarify your code, let the OS do the hard work, etc. As far as the current implementation, using `forCellReuseIdentifier` should load very little data (a dozen cells max). Your memory issue may lay elsewhere.